# How to open a Workbook with a password, disable events

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, copy

How to open a Workbook with a password, disable events, 
and then copy a sheet in background to the second file and save.
I need in VBA, working in a MS-Access and Excel files

I have done this until now, is working.

```
Private Sub TestFunction()

'strPath = CurrentDb.Properties(0)
'strPath = Left(strPath, Len(strPath) - Len(Dir(strPath, vbNormal))) & "Temp\"
Dim CopyFrom As Object
Dim CopyTo As Object ''Early binding: Workbook
Dim CopyThis As Object
Dim xl As Object ''Early binding: New Excel.Application

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
Set CopyFrom = xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\A01.xls")
'CopyFrom.EnableEvents = False
Set CopyThis = CopyFrom.Sheets(1) ''Sheet number 1
Set CopyTo = xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\PM1.xls")
CopyThis.Copy After:=CopyTo.Sheets(CopyTo.Sheets.Count)
CopyFrom.Close
End Sub
```

This opens the Excel, I enter the pass copy's the sheet to second File.

But I need to pass the password in background,  delete the sheet and save the second file, all in background.
Also I need to delete a sheet, without asking me, like :

```
CopyTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
```

Thank you

Comment: xl.Workbooks.Open can take the password as a parameter as well as the filename

Comment: Set CopyFrom = xl.Workbooks.Open("D:\A01.xls", "admin")
Is not working.

Comment: The delete statement will only work if the name of the sheet is actually "Sheet1". Otherwise you just refer to the first sheet as sheets(1) This is just a sidenote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Password issue**

Be careful to check wether it is an "open file" password (`password` parameter) or a "modify file" password (`WriteResPassword` parameter).

Something like:

```
Sub OpenMyFile()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="Path", Password:="OpenFile", WriteResPassword:="WriteFile"
End Sub
```

**Delete without alert**

For your second question, here is what you can do:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts=False
CopyTo.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts=True
```

Comment: It is from VBA Code a Login window with password.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Please have a try and tell us what goes wrong. Btw, I've edited my answer with a solution for the delete